How to model frequency data with mixed effects?
I have some frequency data that I am not sure how to model
I have two independent experiments (replicate: A, B), where I treat neurons (10 per treatment) with the same drug but for different time periods (0, 5, 15 and 45 miunutes) These are my treatments (Pre-treatment is my control). Then, I count particules of different sizes (area) and try to see if the treatment change the distribution of particules sizes. My data is organized like this:
Data1
replicate neuron treatment area
   A        1      pre     0.10 
   A        1      pre     0.07 
   A        1      pre     0.07 
   A        2      pre     0.22 
   A        2      pre     0.19

Then, I added another column of area bins, so my response variable (area) is a count variable
Data2
replicate neuron treatment   area_bin      area
   A        1      pre     [0.03,0.08]      2
   A        1      pre     (0.08,0.13]      1
   A        2      pre     [0.03,0.08]      6
   A        2      pre     (0.08,0.13]      4

Then, I wrote my model like:
m.poisson <- glmmTMB(area ~ treatment * area_bin + (1|replicate) + (1|neuron), 
                  family = poisson, 
                  data = Data2)

¿Is the model correct? The treatment * area_bin makes me doubt
I tried to model with glmmTMB using Poisson, Negative Binomial, Conway-Maxwell Poisson families distributions and everytime similar results: overdispersion and significant KS test.
DHARMa test rises another question for me: the residuals QQplot looks like underdispersion to me, but the test give a dispersion parameter of 1.711 (this is for Poisson). ¿Am I interpreting it wright?

I also tried Observation Level Random Effects (OLRE) approach and I get overdispersion (which I understand is not a problem) and significant KS test (with DHARMa)
Thanks in advance
